# Interface orientation in iPad

Tags: ipad, uitableview, xcode4, orientation

I am using one image in one cell of table in iPad.But when I change the orientation then the proper image is not coming.I set the image size for landscape mode and give the code to autoresize.But when orientation is changed from landscape to portrait then the image in cell is not coming full.What is the way to solve this problem?Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `UIImageView`? If so have you set the `autoresizingMask` (`UIView` property, you probably want `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` | `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`), and the contentMode for the image?